# Rails JQuery get data from html

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I am attempting to use data from an html page in js.coffee script.

The view code is:

```
 <span class="colHeader" data-wostatus-id="<%= wostatus.id %>"><span><%= wostatus.statuscode %></span></span>
```

Inspecting html looks like this:

```
<span class="colHeader" data-wostatus-id="4"><span>WAPR</span></span>
```

So far, so good.

My js.coffee file has:

```
     alert($(this).data('wostatus-id'))
```

And the results I get = undefined

Thanks for the help!

Comment: What about `alert($(this).getAttribute('data-wostatus-id'))`?

Comment: What is `this` here? Looks like it's bound to wrong node.

Comment: Sailor - that didn't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use jQuery and scan the document for whatever has the id:

```
jQuery("[data-wostatus-id]").each (index, elm) ->
    alert(jQuery(elm).attr("data-wostatus-id"))
```

This presumes there are multiple 'ids' on the page (thus the `each`)

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your js.coffee file. It will run only when the DOM is ready, and specifically accesses the `span` element:

```
$ ->
  alert($('span.colHeader').data('wostatus-id'))
```